# Prevent GetAsyncKeyState function from detecting inputs after it is called? C++

Tags: c++

I have a game which is turn based. During your turn, it prompts you for a move and will ask for one key press input. As soon as a key press is detected, the game continues and you are no longer prompted until your next turn.

I am having problems though with GetAsyncKeyState function though because it stores key presses even after it is called.

*From the MSDN website:*
Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, **and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.**

The bolded area is what is causing problems for me, as the user can spam key inputs while it is not his/her turn, then when it becomes his/her turn, the game will prompt the user and instantly confirm an input that was pressed from beforehand.

My function for this is very similar to this:

```
unsigned int getUserInput(){

while (true) //Await a user's input
    {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x31))
            {
                return 1; //User pressed 1 key
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x32))
            {
                return 2; //User pressed 2 key
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x33))
            {
                return 3; //User pressed 3 key
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x34))
            {
                return 4; //User pressed 4 key
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x35))
            {
                return 5; //User pressed 5 key
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x36))
            {
                return 6; //User pressed 6 key
            }
    }
}
```

Should I just not use Asnc Key State in this case? If so, what is a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that `GetAsyncKeyState` returns is a bit field. You can isolate the bit you are looking for with bitwise operations. In your specific case (for detecting if the key is currently pressed), you are looking for the high bit. You can test it like this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x31) & 0x8000)
{
    return 1; //User pressed 1 key
}
```

However, if I am understanding your problem description correctly, I don't think this will fully solve it. It sounds like you want the user to have to press the key down while the function is running (rather than just being able to hold the key down). What you should do for that, is at the beginning of the function check if the key is pressed. If it is, wait for it to be released. Something like this:

```
bool key_is_pressed = true;
while (key_is_pressed) {
    key_is_pressed = false;

    // the key codes you are checking are consecutive,
    // so we can just loop over them
    for (int key = '1'; key <= '6'; ++key) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000))
            key_is_pressed = true;
    }
}
```

Then continue to the part where you wait for a key to be pressed.

Note that the text you highlight, *"and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState"*, could actually have been the solution to your problem. That information is stored in a different bit (the low bit), so you could isolate that and ensure that the key *wasn't* previously pressed. Unfortunately, MSDN clearly documents that this behavior should not be relied upon. So you should pretty much always ignore everything but the hi bit when using `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: Wow... this went a little bit over my head. A few questions: In your first code block, what does 0x8000 mean and why is needed there? In all my GetAsyncKeyState calls, it's just the GetAsyncKeyState(parameter) call.

Comment: @Hatefiend: `0x8000` is a hexadecimal number who's binary  representation is `1000000000000000`. By combining that (using `&`) with the result of the call to `GetAsyncKeystate`, you are masking out all but the most significant bit. The upshot of this is that if that bit is 0, the result of the combination is 0 (which compares as `false` in the if statement), and if that bit is `1`, then the result is non-zero (which compares as `true` in the if statement).

Comment: I also should have been a bit more descriptive with my problem. Sometimes I will require the user to press letter keys and number keys, spacebar, etc so the for loop you made may not work. After really looking over the loop.. it's telling the computer... "okay, did user press key 1? what about key 2? and key 3? etc". I don't see how this is an improvement over: if (key1 pressed) else if (key2 pressed) etc. I don't see how it would fix my problem of having AsycKey still listen for key presses even after the function call has been made.

Comment: Okay so seeing your response... by putting the 0x8000 in there, we are essentially overwhelming the if statement with false unless it TRULY IS a legitimate key press?

Comment: @Hatefiend: The for loop was just a simplification to make the code less cluttered. It's not essential to the answer. What the for loop is doing could also be done with a bunch of if statements. But what the code is doing is *not* what your current code is doing. It's also not a replacement for the code you have, it's an addition. Please read the answer more carefully, I explained what its purpose is.